# Autosys job not failing when the shell script fails

Tags: shell, autosys

I am moving existing manual shell scripts to execute via autosys jobs. However, after adding `exit 1` for each failed autosys job; it is not failing and autosys shows exit code as `0`.
I tried the below simple script

```
#!/bin/ksh
exit 1;
```

When I execute this, the autosys job shows a success status.I have not updated success code or max success code in autosys, everything is default. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure you're executing the above script? Can you add some logging, and verify that? For example, `bash` might not be `/bin/bash` on some systems.

Comment: You are right , this is the correct one which I tried. #!/bin/ksh
exit 1;

Comment: This question is about server management software. Unless you are writing software with the autosys SDK, your question should be asked on [sf] instead.